# Azure SQL Database Left Join looping with 1.5 million records

Tags: sql-server, azure, indexing, query-optimization, azure-sql-database

I have Table Customer_AJ ( customer varchar , Item number , purchase datetime ) , And i have two tables with it Sucess and Failure , And i want all the Failures which does not have sucess in next 30 minutes for that customer .

I tried it bys using Not exist but it is getting looped at hashMatch ( as i saw it in queryplan , Iam attaching the query and screen shot of execution plan ..

```
with Failure as (
        select * from [dbo].[Customer_AJ]  where item in  ( 20, 34, 35, 36, 37, 47, 53, 54 )
        )     ,
success as (
    select * from  Customer_AJ where Item in  ( 1, 3, 40, 42, 43, 5 )
        )     ,
final  as (
        select f.customer, f.item,f.purchase from  Failure  f  left outer join success s
         on f.customer = s.customer and DATEDIFF( minute , f.purchase , s.purchase ) between 0 and 30
         where s.customer is NULL         
        )
    select * from final
```

[Here is the Query Execution plan for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKaWv.png)

Comment: Rather than a screenshot of the live query stats, past the actual execution plan XML to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is going to be the DATEDIFF function on the columns. It's going to lead to scans. If you have millions of rows, that's going to be slow every time. You need to find a way to join the data without applying that function.

Additional suggestions might be possible with a full execution plan, not an image.

Comment: is there any way we can remove datediff function . Especially this conditional join ?

Comment: I don't know the business rules that are driving this, but calculating a date and time value as a variable and then comparing to that variable for each column would be one way to do it. If the rule is to find one that is 30 minutes off the other, then figure out how to capture that value without a calculation in the WHERE, ON or HAVING clauses of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when looking for something that doesn't exists I prefer to use the 'obvious' `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` syntax. The query optimizer will use the same plan as the `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... WHERE field IS NULL` syntax, but it's so much easier to read.

```
SELECT f.customer, f.item, f.purchase
  FROM Failure  f  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM Success s
                     WHERE s.customer = f.customer
                       AND DATEDIFF( minute , f.purchase , s.purchase ) between 0 and 30 )
```

The `DateDiff()` is a performance killer here as there is no way to get a quick path towards the matching data, nor can the optimizer predict how many lines will match. To get around this you might try to convert the `DateDiff()` to a `DateAdd()` construction:

```
SELECT f.customer, f.item, f.purchase
  FROM Failure  f  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM Success s
                     WHERE s.customer = f.customer
                       AND s.purchase >= f.purchase
                       AND s.purchase <= DateAdd(minute, +30, f.purchase) )
```

Assuming you have an index on your `Customer_AJ` table that has the following fields : `customer, item, purchase` this should make the join between `Failure` and `Success` fairly fast.

(You might want to experiment and swap around the order of the fields as it does depend a bit on what your data looks like, but since we have a range of matches for the `purchase` column I'm pretty sure you want to keep that one last).